# How convert LocalDate to ChronoZonedDateTime?

Tags: java, date, datetime, localdate, datetime-conversion

In the code bellow, i'm getting an error in my "if" comparisson. The message says "`isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime<?>) in ChronoZonedDateTime cannot be applied to (java.time.LocalDate)`". How convert LocalDate to `ChronoZonedDateTime`?

```
LocalDate taxBegin = tax.getBeginAt();

if(contract.getBeginAt().isBefore(taxBegin)){
    //do something
}
```

I tried wrapping like *`ChronoZonedDateTime.from(taxBegin)`* but didn't work, it gave me "`DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZoneId from TemporalAccessor: 2019-12-01 of type java.time.LocalDat`"

Comment: What is `contract` variable and what is `getBeginAt()` returning?

Comment: Try the other way `contract.getBeginAt().toLocalDate().isBefore(taxBegin)`

Comment: Karol, contract.getBeginAt() returns a ZonedDateTime value

Comment: Do your contracts really start at a specific time of day? If so, is this specified in a particular time zone, or as a Unix time?

Comment: Sunil, I tried what you said and it worked! Thank you! If you post as an answer, I will mark as the right one

Comment: @SunilDabburi The risk is, of course, that this fixes your compile error while introducing a big logical bug in your code. You need to find out from the requirements, the product owner, or who or whatever process is responsible for requirements clarification in your company, how you should compare a `taxBegin` timestamp (with a particular timezone and time of day) to a contract begin date that has no specified timezone or time of day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to convert a `ZonedDateTime` object into a `LocalDate`, you can use `toLocalDate()` method. Thus, the following code should work for you:

```
LocalDate taxBegin = tax.getBeginAt();

if(contract.getBeginAt().toLocalDate().isBefore(taxBegin)){
    //do something
}
```

Check https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/localdate-zoneddatetime-conversion/ for an example of converting between `ZonedDateTime` and `LocalDate`.

Comment: Same warning applies as to Sunil's answer: just because you converted a ChronoZonedDateTime to a LocalDate, doesn't mean that it is local to the same timezone as the other LocalDate. You also dropped the time part, and you don't know if that is valid for this specific business problem.  The tax object may be specific to a particular country or timezone that is present in another field, which has a particular time associated with the locale tax rules about which day something should be taxed on. The problem of the OP is one of requirements, not of converted a ZonedDateTime to a LocalDate.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [atStartOfDay(ZoneId)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-)
I.E.

```
public static ZonedDateTime convertLocalDate(final LocalDate ld) {
    return ld.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

You could either use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` or `ZoneOffset.UTC`.
Documentation states: If the zone ID is a ZoneOffset, then the result always has a time of midnight.
So your code'll be

```
if (contract.getBeginAt().isBefore(convertLocalDate(taxBegin))) {
    //do something
}
```

If you want to convert it to a specific time, you should use
`taxBegin.atTime(LocalTime).atZone(ZoneId)`.

Comment: This gives the conversion that was asked for and works as a solution. I think it’s easier to use the opposite conversion as in the two other answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you had `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate`, it would have worked just fine. But since you have `LocalDate`, you lost time. Now the only way is to convert the existing `ChronoZonedDateTime` to `LocalDate` and compare. However, this may not always work if the time zones are different.

Same timezone:

```
contract.getBeginAt().toLocalDate().isBefore(taxBegin)
```

Comment: `ChronoZonedDateTime.toLocalDate()` gives you the "local date part of this date-time.
This returns a local date with the same year, month and day as this date-time." ([Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toLocalDate())), which means that it will be in the timezone of the tax date. Which may, or may not, be totally unrelated to the timezone of the contract's begin date. You can't just compare two LocalDate's unless you know that they were intended to be in the same timezone.

Comment: Hi Erwin. Yes you are right. I knew that... since the user wasn't using `LocalDateTime`, I felt there is no clear way to compare. We can get the `ZoneId` from `ChronoZonedDateTime` but we cannot use in `LocalDate` properly to compare. But, you are right I should have made my explanation more clear.